# Piping commands into the Python REPL

Tags: python, read-eval-print-loop

I have a file containing Python statements, and I'd like to run Python in such a way that it prints to stdout what would be shown if those commands were run in the REPL.

For example, if the file is

```
1 + 4
'a' + 'b'
```

Then the output should be

```
>>> 1 + 4
5
>>> 'a' + 'b'
'ab'
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Windows ? *n*x ? Cross-platform ?

Comment: Linux, though I'd really hope there'd be a cross-platform approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`replwrap`](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/replwrap.html?highlight=replwrap#module-pexpect.replwrap) from [`pexpect`](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) to achieve this goal, even has a [`python`](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/replwrap.html?highlight=replwrap#pexpect.replwrap.python) method:

```
from pexpect import replwrap

with open("commands.txt", "r") as f:
    commands = [command.strip() for command in f.readlines()]

repl = replwrap.python()
for command in commands:
   print ">>>", command
   print repl.run_command(command),
```

Which returns:

```
python replgo.py 
>>> 1 + 4
5
>>> 'a' + 'b'
'ab'
```

You'll need to get the latest version of pexpect.

Comment: This should be replaced by the newer, simpler and self contained answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67511928/1950432 It requires no third party libraries, and should work almost anywhere you have python interpreter and a unix shell.

Answer (score 4):

(not so) quick and (mostly) dirty, using the [code](https://docs.python.org/2/library/code.html) module:

```
import sys
import code

infile = open('cmd.py')
def readcmd(prompt):
    line = infile.readline()
    if not line:
        sys.exit(0)

    print prompt,line.rstrip()
    return line.rstrip()

code.interact(readfunc=readcmd)
```

Lots of room for improvement, but it's late here. Anyway, example:

```
sh$ cat cmd.py
1 + 4
'a' + 'b'

1/0

def f(x):
    return x*2

f(3)
sh$ python console.py 
Python 2.7.3 (default, Mar 13 2014, 11:03:55) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>>  1 + 4
5
>>>  'a' + 'b'
'ab'
>>>  
>>>  1/0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
>>>  
>>>  def f(x):
...      return x*2
...  
>>>  f(3)
6
```

Answer (score 3):

Some ast magic can help here:

```
import ast
import itertools


def main():
    with open('test.txt', 'r') as sr:
        parsed = ast.parse(sr.read())
        sr.seek(0)
        globals_ = {}
        locals_ = {}
        prev_lineno = 0
        for node in ast.iter_child_nodes(parsed):
            source = '\n'.join(itertools.islice(sr, 0, node.lineno - prev_lineno))[:-1]
            print('>>> {}'.format(source))
            if isinstance(node, ast.Expr):
                print(eval(source, globals_, locals_))
            else:
                exec(source, globals_, locals_)
            prev_lineno = node.lineno

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Input:

```
1 + 4
'a' + 'b'
a = 1
a
```

Output:

```
>>> 1 + 4
5
>>> 'a' + 'b'
ab
>>> a = 1
>>> a
1
```

What this does is to find the start and end line numbers of each individual statement by parsing the source using the `ast` module, then calling either `eval` or `exec` depending on whether it was a statement or an expression.

The context is saved in `globals_` and `locals_`.

You can possibly make this safer by using some python sandbox to perform the `eval` and `exec`.

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe your input to pythons "code" module. It will show the output, but won't show the input.

```
$ echo '1 + 1' | python -m code
Python 2.7.10 (v2.7.10:15c95b7d81dc, May 23 2015, 09:33:12) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> 2
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do this by tricking the Python command into starting an interactive session. This can be done with `unbuffer`, usually provided alongside the `expect` tool in Linux distros. This approach is pretty general, and will work for all sorts of programs which behave differently when they're called interactively.

The following command will start a REPL, even though the (currently empty) input is coming from a pipe:

```
$ printf '' | unbuffer -p python3
Python 3.8.8 (default, Feb 19 2021, 11:04:50)
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

A couple of annoying behaviours make this work a little differently to an interactive session. Firstly, `unbuffer` will exit as soon as it encounters EOF, so we need a small delay to ensure Python has enough time to start up:

```
$ (sleep 1; printf '') | unbuffer -p python3
Python 3.8.8 (default, Feb 19 2021, 11:04:50)
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Notice that this time we managed to get a `>>>` prompt.

Secondly, our input commands won't get echoed as part of the output. For example:

```
$ (sleep 1; printf 'print("a" * 10)\n'; sleep 1) | unbuffer -p python3
Python 3.8.8 (default, Feb 19 2021, 11:04:50)
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> aaaaaaaaaa
>>>
```

Notice that our input `print("a" * 10)\n` doesn't appear after the `>>>` prompt, even though the result does get printed.

We can fix this using `tee` to duplicate our commands to both stdout and to the REPL (which we execute using process substitution):

```
$ (sleep 1; printf 'print("a" * 10)\n'; sleep 1) | tee >(unbuffer -p python3)
Python 3.8.8 (default, Feb 19 2021, 11:04:50)
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print("a" * 10)
aaaaaaaaaa
>>>
```

This seems to behave properly, but we have to put delays between each line. Here's a script which will do that automatically, reading lines from stdin:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

cat | (sleep 1; while IFS='' read -r LINE
do
 sleep 0.2
 echo "$LINE"
done; sleep 1) | tee >(unbuffer -p python3)
```

This seems to do the job (I'm using `printf` but this would work equally well with a separate file; note that the REPL needs two newlines to execute an indented block, just like in an interactive session):

```
$ printf 'if True:\n  print("hello")\nelse:\n  print("world")\n\n12345\n' | ./repl.sh
Python 3.8.8 (default, Feb 19 2021, 11:04:50)
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> if True:
...   print("hello")
... else:
...   print("world")
...
hello
>>> 12345
12345
>>>
```

We can pipe this through standard text processing tools like `head` and `tail` if you want to remove the final `>>>` and the startup noise, e.g.

```
$ printf 'if True:\n  print("hello")\nelse:\n  print("world")\n\n12345\n' | ./repl.sh | tail -n+4 | head -n-1
>>> if True:
...   print("hello")
... else:
...   print("world")
...
hello
>>> 12345
12345
```